# Simple proxy server for web services

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I am looking for a proxy server for web services primarily for port forwarding in the DMZ  environment. Previously I have used Amberpoint or Data Power for this purpose. Now, in my new project I do not have access to any proxy servers and the traffic is pretty light at a maximum of 100 requests/day.

I looked at Managed Service Engine from MS, but since it is still in beta I can't use it. Any  help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the traffic is that light, then why do you need a proxy server?

Comment: The application is being hosted in a DMZ location and the Network team dont like to open port 80. The back end services I am calling are running on port 80 and can not be changed to different port.

Comment: I have had a look at thes MSDN articles(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500646.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546553.aspx), but could not figure out using them for a bunch of end points.

Comment: I can't initially see why you can't throw a $50 router with port-forwarding at the problem. (e.g. anything running Tomato firmware). Probably cheaper / more maintainable than any software solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two article describe a way to achieve the solution.

[Building a WCF Router, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500646.aspx)

[Building A WCF Router, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546553.aspx)

A WCF router example also describes this problem in MSDN wcf samples.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [WCF Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795218.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks Matt. This is the functionality I am looking for. But the example you mentioned is part of .net 4.0. Does it work in .net 3.5 and for asmx services?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options:

- Build your own router, for example based on the sample from Michele Leroux Bustamante which you linked to.
- Use a standard product, for example Amberpoint
- Upgrade to .net 4.0 and use functionality available in the framework

If think of what is the cheapest option in the short term and what gives the simplest and most maintainable solution in the long run, for your project.

I do not know your exact situation, but I would have tried to upgrade the solution to .net 4.0 if possible. This reduces the number of products involved and the amount of code that you have to write.

Comment: Amberpoint or Datapower are out of question because of project budget. I have already started building a Router based one of the WCF-WF samples from MSDN